# Is it recommended to add SSL certificate protection to the domain's subdomains (webmail,webdisk,cpanel)?

Tags: https, security-certificate

I bought web hosting under FastComet and they have a free `Let's Encrypt SSL` service that comes with the package. There is an option to include the domain's subdomains (webmail,webdisk,cpanel) to install the certificates to, but I don't know if I need to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason not to do it.

If you go read your emails through `webmail.example.com` do you want anyone to be able to read them also, and maybe change them in the path? If not, you need HTTPS, and hence you need a certificate (either specifically for `webmail.example.com` or a wildcard one of `*.example.com`).

Browsers are more and more leaning towards HTTPS everywhere, so any `http://` resource will soon become highly suspicious.

In a world nowadays where you can easily have free and automated certificates, there is no reason not to do HTTPS.

Of course the above is a simplification, since after getting a certificate you still need to configure (or have someone configure) your webhosting correctly. It does not buy much if you have a certificate but still do TLS 1.0 for example, this would be vulnerable to an active attacker.